# Rerun javascript function when screen orientation changes

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, orientation

I'm using a code that scale images to fit the parent div, it's called "aspectcorrect".
The problem happens on the mobile version: my parent div has 100% width, and when the user changes the  orientation of the screen to landscape, the image doesn't resize to fit the new div's width.

There is a way to rerun the onload event (which scales the image), when the user changes the orientation of the screen?

Here is my website: www.mcsoftware.com.br/sitemc
I'm still working on it.

(To understand what I'm saying, open it on your cellphone, and when you change the screen orientation just click on "Continuar mesmo assim" to navigate)

Thanks!

aspectcorrect.js

```
function ScaleImage(srcwidth, srcheight, targetwidth, targetheight, fLetterBox) {

    var result = { width: 0, height: 0, fScaleToTargetWidth: true };

    if ((srcwidth <= 0) || (srcheight <= 0) || (targetwidth <= 0) || (targetheight <= 0)) {
        return result;
    }

    // scale to the target width
    var scaleX1 = targetwidth;
    var scaleY1 = (srcheight * targetwidth) / srcwidth;

    // scale to the target height
    var scaleX2 = (srcwidth * targetheight) / srcheight;
    var scaleY2 = targetheight;

    // now figure out which one we should use
    var fScaleOnWidth = (scaleX2 > targetwidth);
    if (fScaleOnWidth) {
        fScaleOnWidth = fLetterBox;
    }
    else {
        fScaleOnWidth = !fLetterBox;
    }

    if (fScaleOnWidth) {
        result.width = Math.floor(scaleX1);
        result.height = Math.floor(scaleY1);
        result.fScaleToTargetWidth = true;
    }
    else {
        result.width = Math.floor(scaleX2);
        result.height = Math.floor(scaleY2);
        result.fScaleToTargetWidth = false;
    }
    result.targetleft = Math.floor((targetwidth - result.width) / 2);
    result.targettop = Math.floor((targetheight - result.height) / 2);

    return result;
}
```

onimageload.js

```
function OnImageLoad(evt) {

    var img = evt.currentTarget;

    // what's the size of this image and it's parent
    var w = $(img).width();
    var h = $(img).height();
    var tw = $(img).parent().width();
    var th = $(img).parent().height();

    // compute the new size and offsets
    var result = ScaleImage(w, h, tw, th, false);

    // adjust the image coordinates and size
    img.width = result.width;
    img.height = result.height;
    $(img).css("left", result.targetleft);
    $(img).css("top", result.targettop);
}
```

Where onload function goes

```
<img onload="OnImageLoad(event);" />
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ffxeqq21/

Comment: Please provide any relevant code to your issue.

Comment: just check the post again, there is more information now...

Answer (score 0):

You can try some javascript library like [jQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) and use the [orientationchange event](http://api.jquerymobile.com/orientationchange/)  This way you could just do

```
$( window ).on( "orientationchange", function( event ) {
  //Some code
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but which code? There is more information on my post now, check it please. :)

Comment: I guess I need to rerun the onload event on the img tag.

<img onload="OnImageLoad(event);" />

Right? But how do I insert that on the code you gave to me?

Comment: Where it says `//some code` put your code (a simple call to your function). You need to include jQuery Mobile first (the link is on my answer).
also remember to use `$(document).ready(function(){    });`

Comment: Didn't work. I tried inserting aspectcorrect.js and onimageload.js on the tag but both don't rerun the javascript, the image stays with the same size.
I did the right thing?

Comment: Well, try removing the dollar sign from your `onimageload.js` because you already have the img var, something like this `$(img).width();` -> `img.width();`. Do that on all the lines where you use your var. If that don't make any changes, then I would look at the chrome console, and use some breakpoints on your source. To make that go press `f12` then go to `source` and find your javascript code. Click on the number of the line that you want to inspect and refresh your page.

Comment: check the fiddle I added to the post.
but I guess it's not possible to see the problem on mobile fiddle.

Comment: Well I see a couple of problems thanks to your fiddle. First, this statement `var img = evt.currentTarget;` return an HTML Object, not a jQuery object, that means that you can't use methods like `img.parent()` so check that issue. The other problem is that I can't access to the parent element of the image width, in fact, I can't get any of the css properties of that div with javascript, bu I can see them in chrome inspector... Now I don't know why is that happening.

Comment: did u open the website on your phone? 
www.mcsoftware.com.br/sitemc 
I don't know what to do now...